# nginx not binding to all interfaces

Tags: nginx

I write a new default conf (overwriting the default default conf) but the files are only served locally. However the files are not served outside the localhost

```
curl my_ip/a >> not found
curl 127.0.0.1/a >> "it works!"
```

(a is a file in /var/www/html)

Here is my config

```
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /test {
        stub_status on;
    }
   location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

According to some articles I tried to add an root directive in the location /, use index instead of try_files ...
What I can't understand is if I replace *:80 with the local interface IP (192.168.1.x) then it working on the LAN/from the internet but no more from the localhost.

It seems that nginx listens only to one interface (whereas *:80 or 80 should listen to all).

curling the index.html (from public IP or localhost) serves the file but not the one under /var/www/html but the default one /use/share/nginx..)

I have other configs enabled but none have the default_server or server_name _; directives.

according to nginx.conf only the /etc/nginx/site-enabled folder is searched for conf.

Btw I have two nic.

Thank you for your help :)

UPDATE : it is now working

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

root /var/www/html;
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
}
```

The problem must have been elsewhere but not idea where ...

Comment: So if you change it to `listen 192.168.1.x:80` it works from the internet but not when you do `curl 127.0.0.1/a`?

Comment: what happens when you change *:80 to just :80?

Comment: @Shawn C. yes  exactly

Comment: @Regmi i get this error nginx: [emerg] no host in ":80" of the "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:22

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix your problem?   I'm encountering it too.

Comment: Hi, not really; I almost forgot it. I tried today and it works (I posted the current config file but I can't see any difference except listen 80; )

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add, in case of the situation where you upgrade nginx and now your sites are not working - it's because nginx default is to create empty site on port 80 HTTP, and not include your sites.  You need to modify /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*  (and remove the site in /etc/nginx/conf.d).  It's really strange that the install program doesn't try to preserve this.